# Is kryo unable to serialize objects larger than 2 gigabytes?

Tags: apache-spark, serialization

I've read that the max size of kryo buffer in spark can be 2048 mb, and it should be larger than the largest object that my program will serialize (source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html). But what should I do if my largest object is larger than 2gb? Do I have to use the java serializer in that case? Or does the java serializer also have this limitation of 2g?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why Kryo cannot handle things larger than 2GB is because it uses the primitives of Java, using the Java Byte Arrays to setup the buffer. The limit of Java Byte Arrays are 2Gb. That is the main reason why Kryo has this limitation. This check done in Spark is to avoid the error to happens during execution time creating an even larger issue for you to debug and handle the code.

For more details please take a look [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6405).

Comment: I know that. Does java serializer work differently? Can it handle larger size objects? What should I do if I want larger than 2GB objects to be serialized?

Comment: Also when we're talking about size, are we referring to the size of an object to be serialized, or an object that has been serialized?

Comment: The Java Serialiser will handle objects larger than 2Gb with no issue. The Kryo is for faster transformations. And about the size, the 2Gb is the size of the object before Kryo compress it.

Comment: Are you sure that it's before kryo compresses it? Because I have a spark job where I create a 3gb object and kryo compresses it down to 724 mb. (I looked at the storage tab in Spark UI, and also logged the size of the object when it was prased into a scala case class from json, using SizeEstimator).

Comment: According to the documentation of Spark it seems the case:
`Maximum allowable size of Kryo serialization buffer, in MiB unless otherwise specified. This must be larger than any object you attempt to serialize and must be less than 2048m. Increase this if you get a "buffer limit exceeded" exception inside Kryo.`

Comment: When the documentation says, the size should be larger than the object you are attempt to serialize it seems that is the case.

Comment: As per documentation, you are correct. I will try to cache the dataset with that object using MEMORY_ONLY_SER storage level tomorrow and see if it serializes that 3 gig object. Maybe my code doesn't use serialization after all. The size of the object is definitely larger than 3 gigs, according to the SizeEstimator object.

Comment: Hello, so, today I ran my spark job again and it does serialize that object and it is larger than 2 gigs, idk how kryo did it, maybe it compresses it first somehow. When I switched to the java serializer, by the way, I got an error, saying: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit", so it seems that java serializer cannot handle any size objects, it is limited to 2 gigs as well.

Comment: That is very interesting, well that use to have some limits in Spark related to the 2Gb. But is really good to know about it. I've found a ticket related to those problems that were resolved on version 2.4.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235